# Get the id of the "comment" i am replying to (JSP)

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have created a for loop to display all the value from database, a textfield and button.
So for each value displayed there will be one textfield and "reply" button. 
So when i click on the "reply" button, the text in the textfield and together with the id of the value i am "replying" to will be store into database.
But how am i suppose to get the id of the specific value i am "replying" to?
Below is the code in the jsp page

```
        <%  
    ConnectionDB uDB = new ConnectionDB();
    Comment[] comment = uDB.getComment();
        %> 
    <%
     for (int i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) {
    %> 
             <%=uDB.getMemberName(comment[i].getMemberId()).getFirstName()%>
             <%=uDB.getMemberName(comment[i].getMemberId()).getLastName()%>
             <%=comment[i].getCommentDesc() %>
          <br><input type="text" name="replycommenttxt" size="20"> 
              <input type="submit" name="replycommentbutton" value="reply"  >
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a hidden field of your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name"parentCommentId" value="<%= comment[i].getId() %>" />
```

You should really learn about the JSP EL, the JSTL, and the MVC pattern. Reading data from a database in a JSP and using scriptlets is really bad practice.

Comment: Ok. Noted. Thanks. I got the Id however it is the id of the 1st row of the for loop. How am i suppose to get the id of the other values? Below is the code in the servlet to call the id and txtfield.                                                                Member m = (Member)session.getAttribute("memberinfo");
   int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parentCommentId"));
   replycomment.setMemberId(m.getMemberId());
   replycomment.setCommentdId(i);
   replycomment.setReplyDesc(request.getParameter("replycommenttxt"));

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Make sure to generate one form per comment, and not a single form for all your comments.

Comment: Ok. Understood. i go try out.

Comment: I have generated one form per comment. However only the button of the first comment will go to my servlet whereas the rest doesnt. Do you know why? Below is the code where i generate the form for each comment.

Comment: '<%
for (int i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) {
       %><form>
       <input type="hidden" name="parentCommentId"
            value="<%= comment[i].getCommentId() %>" />
                                        <%=uDB.getMemberName(comment[i].getMemberId()).getFirstName()%>                    <%=uDB.getMemberName(comment[i].getMemberId()).getLastName()%>
<%=comment[i].getCommentDesc()%>
<br>
<input type="text" name="replycommenttxt" size="20"> <input
type="submit" name="replycommentbutton" value="reply"> </form><% } %>'

Comment: Specify the action attribute of the `<form>` element. And check that your generated HTML is valid.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer, and upvote it. That's how you say thanks here.

Comment: <%
for (int i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) { %>
<form method="post" action="/Utopia/CommentServlet">
<input type="hidden" name="parentCommentId" value="<%=comment[i].getCommentId() %>" />
<%=uDB.getMemberName(comment[i].getMemberId()).getFirstName()%>            <%=uDB.getMemberName(comment[i].getMemberId()).getLastName()%>
<%=comment[i].getCommentDesc()%>  <br>
<textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="replycommenttxt"></textarea>
<input         type="submit" name="replycommentbutton" value="reply"> </form><% } %>

Comment: So i basically add in the action to the form. Thanks! =]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "ParameterValues" with 'for' clause to get the other ids that you want.

```
Member m = (Member)session.getAttribute("memberinfo");
String[] parentCommentId=request.getParameter("parentCommentId"));
replycomment.setMemberId(m.getMemberId()); replycomment.setCommentdId(i);
replycomment.setReplyDesc(request.getParameter("replycommenttxt"));
```